# Set HTTP 1.1 for sam local start-api

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-sam, aws-sam-cli

I'm developing a lambda function and using AWS SAM to build my stack. I've noticed that when I test locally using `sam local start-api`, the API responds with HTTP 1.0 for HTTP 1.1 requests. Here's a sample output from curl:

```
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:3000...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 3000 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: 127.0.0.1:3000
> User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
* HTTP 1.0, assume close after body
< HTTP/1.0 403 FORBIDDEN
< Content-Type: application/json
< Content-Length: 43
< Server: Werkzeug/1.0.1 Python/3.7.10
< Date: Fri, 03 Dec 2021 04:21:40 GMT
< 
{ [43 bytes data]
* Closing connection 0
{
    "message": "Missing Authentication Token"
}
```

As you can see in the output above, an HTTP 1.1 request is sent to the API but the API responds with HTTP 1.0. This happens for all requests.

I assume that when I push this out to AWS, the API will also use HTTP 1.0. Does anyone know if I can configure which HTTP protocol version gets used for API gateway proxy to lambda function? Also, how do I set a minimum TLS version of 1.2?

Answer (score 0):

Tell curl to use http 1.1:

`curl http://api-url -vvv --http1.1`